# Spacemacs: Cannot open load file: git-gutter+

Tags: spacemacs, emacs24.4

I'm trying install `spacemacs` on elementary OS,

`emacs --version`: GNU Emacs 24.3.1

```
emacs --daemon
(Spacemacs) --> refreshing package archive: marmalade... [1/4]
Contacting host: marmalade-repo.org:443
Contacting host: marmalade-repo.org:443
Saving file /home/mateuspv/.emacs.d/elpa/archives/marmalade/archive-contents...
Loading vc-git...
Loading vc-git...done
Wrote /home/mateuspv/.emacs.d/elpa/archives/marmalade/archive-contents
(Spacemacs) --> refreshing package archive: melpa... [2/4]
Contacting host: melpa.org:443
Contacting host: melpa.org:443
Saving file /home/mateuspv/.emacs.d/elpa/archives/melpa/archive-contents...
Wrote /home/mateuspv/.emacs.d/elpa/archives/melpa/archive-contents
(Spacemacs) --> refreshing package archive: org... [3/4]
Contacting host: orgmode.org:80
Contacting host: orgmode.org:80
Saving file /home/mateuspv/.emacs.d/elpa/archives/org/archive-contents...
Wrote /home/mateuspv/.emacs.d/elpa/archives/org/archive-contents
(Spacemacs) --> refreshing package archive: gnu... [4/4]
Contacting host: elpa.gnu.org:443
Saving file /home/mateuspv/.emacs.d/elpa/archives/gnu/archive-contents...
Wrote /home/mateuspv/.emacs.d/elpa/archives/gnu/archive-contents
(Spacemacs) --> installing package: git-gutter+@version-control... [1/3]
(Spacemacs) --> installing package: git-gutter-fringe+@version-control... [2/3]
(Spacemacs) --> installing package: helm-flx@spacemacs-base... [3/3]
Error (use-package): git-gutter+ :**init: Cannot open load file: git-gutter+**
Truncate long lines enabled
```

How can I fix that?

Comment: Is `git-gutter+.el[c]` in your `load-path`? If not, put it there.

Comment: git-gutter+ requires Emacs 24.4 or higher version.

Comment: @Drew I'm new in emacs/spacemacs in general, how should I do it?

Comment: @syohex I just update/build Emacs to 24.5.1 and get same error.

Comment: Move `git-gutter+.el[c]` to a directory that is in your `load-path` (a variable you can set in your init file. To find out about it: (1) Use `C-h f load-path`. (2) Use `C-h r i load-path` to read about it in the Emacs manual.

Comment: Having the same problem in Emacs 25.2.2 (spacemacs). I use package-install to install git-gutter and then it works in the current session, but after restarting emacs I get the error above and have to install it again to make it work.

Comment: Turned out that I had not understood spacemacs properly. Additional packages needs to be added in `dotspacemacs-additional-packages` in .spacemacs, not using `M-x package-install`.